# Laravel Cart Updating the latest product only

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, cart

Trying to update the quantity of the products of cart.But only the last element of the cart is updating,others are not updating also other products are getting same quantity as last one.

```
public function update_cart(Request $request,$Fid)
{   

    $data5=array();
    $data5['qty']=$request->qty;

    //print_r($data5['qty']);
    DB::table('cart')
     ->where('Fid',$Fid)
     ->update($data5);
     return redirect('/customer_show_cart');

}
```

Blade.php here in a foreach loop

```
     @foreach ($all_cart_product as $cart_product)
     <td>
<input type="number" style="width: 10%;" name="qty" min="1"  value="{{$cart_product->qty}}"> 
</td>

<td>

<button class="btn btn-default"  formaction="{{URL::to('/update_cart/'.$cart_product->Fid)}}"  
type="submit" style="background-color: green;color: white;">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"> </i>
</button>
```

Comment: What would you expect?  You are updating only the row where `Fid = $Fid`

Comment: trying to update the quantity  of a  row using Fid

Comment: Your question stated that only the last item was getting updated.  Your routine updates one item.  What is the problem?